# does wrapfig package conflicts with OSX 10.9.5?

Tags: formatting, positioning, wrapfigure

I used once the wrapfig package on a windows machine. but on the mac it holds whitespaces beneath the wrapped figure and in this case look of the document is completely insufficient anymore!

please see the pic below:

[image]

I tried to control the so called "number of shot lines", but it didn't work for me.

What makes me sure, that the problem corresponds to the wrapfig package is, that when I include a normal figure, everything works well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have the possibility to compile your document on some other platform? Like this you could answer the question yourself. I do not think that there is a problem between your OS and some package. You should give us a minimal but compilable code which gives you that error and we will try (or correct) it.

Answer (score 2):

Without any code and with the relevant parts of the image smudged out it is very hard to give advice, but the operating system is more or less always irrelevant to TeX. What might be relevant is that you have a newer or older version of some package on the different machines, adding `\listfiles` to the preamble and comparing the generated lists should make it easy to check for version differences if you have both machines available.

However

[image]

Despite the obfuscation that looks suspiciously like a bullet from an itemized list? If it is, this comment in `wrapfig`s documentation is probably relevant:

> - You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or
>     or immediately before or immediately after one.  It is OK to follow
>     a list if there is a blank line ("\par") in between.

Comment: thank you for your responce. I am sorry about the smudged image, but it is meant to be an introduction for students, so I am not allowed to publish it yet.

On the other hand, here is a piece of my code:

`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}[0.25\width]{5cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{../photos/fileStructure.png}
\captionof{figure}{Dateienaufbau unter Linux, wobei {\color{red}Rot markierte Ordner} sind Systemordner.}
\label{fig:fileStructure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\section*{Einleitung}`

I hope this part is sufficient :)

Comment: @user2804070 I realise that's why you did the image but such a question (and uncompilable code fragments) make it very hard for anyone to answer. _All_ questions should really have a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that generates the problem: we are not interested in your text you can just replace every letter by `x`